# Does macOS support HDR wallpapers?

Tags: macos, wallpaper, hdr

There was an [article](https://www.windowscentral.com/software-apps/windows-11/windows-11-is-getting-true-hdr-desktop-wallpaper-support-and-better-screen-casting)

> Windows 11 is getting true HDR desktop wallpaper support and better
> screen casting

Are HDR wallpapers supported on macOS? If yes which version? Can it cause burn in issues?

Comment: Do you have any HDR images? What happens if you try it? HDR seems to be a native recognised format -- I created a dummy .hdr file, and I could select it in Wallpaper settings panel. (But because it wasn't a real image, I just got the default wallpaper.)

Comment: @benwiggy I have seen WWDC23 video about macOS Sonoma supporting 16-bit PNG EDR + 10-bit HDR HEIF. Previous macOS could only open 16-bit PNG but never save as/export (preview.app). Haven’t tried Sonoma beta yet. I partly know the answer about burnins - Macbooks/Apple manufactured displays have LCD. However there might be OLEDs and windows is bringing HDR support which is worrisome for burnins.

Comment: I have tried HDR file (HDR file extension) from WWDC21 sample code and if I set it to a wallpaper -> it is displayed as SDR. (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/hdr_content/processing_hdr_images_with_metal)